# Force-Layout links all being removed when updating with new data (d3 v 4.0)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my first question here so bear with me...

I've made a Force-Directed graph using the d3 inbuilt force layout. This works find on the initial load, but when I try to reload with new data (using onchange with a select element), all the links disappear from the force layout.
The data seems to be updating correctly, in that the correct links are still present in the data, I just can't understand why the links aren't coming through as lines in the svg element.

I've made a js fiddle to show how I'm doing it:
https://jsfiddle.net/onlyskin/f5a4uxje/
(run and then select either 'size' or 'colour' from the dropdown - the expected behaviour is for the appropriate nodes and links to disappear).

The update function looks like this:

```
function update() {
    var pointGroup = nodeGroup.selectAll('.node')
        .data(data.nodes, function(d) { return d ? d.id : this.id; });

    pointGroup.exit().remove();

    var newNodeGroups = pointGroup.enter().append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node');

    newNodeGroups.append('circle')
          .attr('r', function(d) { return circleRadius[d.type] });

    newNodeGroups.append('text')
          .text(function(d) { return d.id; })
          .attr('class', function(d) { return d.type; });

    var allLinks = linkGroup.selectAll('line')
        .data(data.links, function(d) { return d.source+'-'+d.target; });

    allLinks.exit().remove();

    newLinks = allLinks.enter().append('line')
        .attr('class', 'link');

    var circles = nodeGroup.selectAll('circle');
    var text = nodeGroup.selectAll('text');
    var lines = linkGroup.selectAll('line');

    function ticked() {
        lines
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        circles
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        text
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }

    simulation
        .on('tick', ticked)
        .restart();
};
```